# Bash: Split with 2 factors / variables

Tags: bash, algorithm, shell, csv, sh

I want to split a file with the following algorithm.

This CSV has a 3600 lines previously ordered by Name alpabetically ( `sort -k2 -n file.csv` )

Currently I can run this command to split the file in equal number of lines:
`split -l ${MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES} filename.csv ${new_file_pattern}.`

But the original requirement is:
Split into chunks of `${MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES}` **UNLESS** no more records with the first letter of the column 2 exists.

For example:
if I have `${MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES} = 3`, I can split the file in chunk of 300 lines if no more occurrencies of the last first letter of the column are found.

If the LINE 301 has a record with "Arboreal Peaches" the script has to add to the current chunk no matter the `${MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINE}` was already reach.

Is sort of confusing explanation.. I hope any of you can help me (I already spent 2 days in this algorithm)

**UPDATE**

`${MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES} = 3`

Example CSV (with fewer lines for exaple purpose).
Split command reaches ${MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES}, but the line 4 already has a record with the letter A

```
'Aberdeen Research", 'Los Angeles', 'California' 
'Aplueyo Labs", 'Los Angeles', 'US' 
'Acar Media Group", 'Los Angeles', 'US' 
'Aberdeen Research", 'San Jose', 'US' 
'Beethoven Inc", 'San Jose', 'US'
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

Splitted Files

1

```
'Aberdeen Research", 'Los Angeles', 'California' 
'Aplueyo Labs", 'Los Angeles', 'US' 
'Acar Media Group", 'Los Angeles', 'US' 
'Aberdeen Research", 'San Jose', 'US'
```

2

```
'Beethoven Inc", 'San Jose', 'US'
```

Comment: How about you post a workable sample of your file and desired output?

Comment: @JamesBrown already updated! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? In awk:

```
$ cat split.awk
BEGIN {if(max=="") 
    print "Invalid numer of lines"; exit     # exit if no max
}
(a=substr($0,2,1)) && ++c>=max && prev!=a {  # first letter to a, if count >= max
    c=0                                      # and first letter changes
    fc++                                     # reset count and filemask counter
} 
{
    print $0 > (mask==""?"x":mask) (fc==""?0:fc)  # write to file default mask x 
    prev=a                                   # remember previous first letter
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -v max=3 -v mask="file" -f split.awk file.csv
$ cat file0
'Aberdeen Research", 'Los Angeles', 'California' 
'Aplueyo Labs", 'Los Angeles', 'US' 
'Acar Media Group", 'Los Angeles', 'US' 
'Aberdeen Research", 'San Jose', 'US' 
$ cat file1
'Beethoven Inc", 'San Jose', 'US'
```

`mask` is the filename prefix or `$new_file_pattern` and `max` is `$MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES`, ie. in the command line set `-v max=$MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES -v mask=$new_file_pattern`.

Comment: Surely the second output file will be `file1`?

Comment: I will try this right now! Let you know any result!